# Sold MacBook; FileVault enabled

Tags: filevault

I sold my MacBook earlier and I want to reinstall Yosemite.

However, I have FileVault enabled and I want to essentially "throw away the key" and "reinstall Yosemite" so none of the data is recoverable.

Could someone please clarify what I should do? Many thanks.

Comment: What version of OS X do you have installed now?

Comment: Have you already sold the MacBook - or are you in the process of preparing it to sell? Your question doesn't make much sense if you have already sold the macbook, i.e. you don't have it anymore.